# Apache Airflow(v2.7) DAG not showing up in the Webserver

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Im very new to Apache Airflow and am using Docker Desktop to run it. Following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9AnJ9_ZAXE), Im trying to run my DAG. Ive pretty much done exactly everything mentioned and looked through the Airflow documentation as well. However, reading a bunch suggestions everywhere, I cant seem to find a solution to my starter issue.

1. When I start Docker(desktop), I run the app.
2. In terminal, I run the command `docker-compose up -d`. This initiates, webserver, scheduler, triggerer & postgres in a container. For *airflow-innit-1*, the status reads "exited".
3. In my Apache Webserver, [image: airflow webserver].

I previously ran the command that deletes the default volumes in it, however it still shows "53" next to the "ALL" tab. Is this indicating that Ive done something wrong?

2. How do I get my DAG to show up and essentially run this test task?

To give you a clearer picture of my DAG;

```
from **airflow** import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator


default_args = {
    "owner":"Q",
    "retries":5,
    "retry_delay":datetime(minute=2)
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="first_dag",
    default_args=default_args
    description="hopefully this works",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 29),
    scheduler_interval="@daily"
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id = "1st_task",
        bash_command = "This is the 1st task completed"
    )

    task1
```

*Note: i have bolded the airflow in the DAG code above to represent the yellow wiggly line underneath it, that represents some error.*

I have also tried to use pip to install airflow in this particular folder, however that request has already been satisfied as stated via my terminal.

Comment: the squiggly on the import statement probably means you haven't installed airflow locally. Since you're using docker, this likely isn't a problem. What version of Airflow are you running?

Comment: Precisely, however when I type `airflow --version` in my terminal. It returns "command not found: airflow". Therein, lies the issue. Please do correct me if Im doing something wrong here. However, the version I installed was 2.7.

Comment: Are you sure it was installed? How did you install it?

Comment: I took the code from the official Airflow Github repository. 
`pip install 'apache-airflow==2.7.1' \ --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.7.1/constraints-3.8.txt"`. Ran it again just now, and now its says that it unable to install cause it couldnt run google-re2

Comment: Check out [this discussion on the Airflow github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/32852) about google-re2 issues. The solution should be in there somewhere :)